# Slow Mailbox Migration "within" Exchange 2016 databases on same server

Tags: migration, mailbox, exchange-2016

We have recently migrated from exchange 2010 to 2016. Everything went smooth until one day we had to fail Veeam replication to DR site. One of the databases crashed and had to be restored from backup. since then, this database frequently goes in dirty shutdown and has to be mounted with -AcceptDataloss switch. 
In short, we decided to move mailboxes from this database to a new one. There are around 175 mailboxes with 350 GB data. We are trying to migrate in batches of 10s and 15s but its verrryyyyy slow. it takes days to migrate 4-5 users. i enabled exchange throttling for this activity as recommended on 
" https://justaucguy.wordpress.com/2018/08/24/slow-mailbox-moves-in-exchange-2016/ " but still not getting 100%.

Anyone can give any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying the operations mentioned in [this similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d5916245-b826-4f5c-baaf-a690ee4bac72/exchange-2010-to-2016-mailbox-migration-very-very-slow?forum=Exch2016SD)?

“MSExchangeMailboxReplication.exe.config” file located at “C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin”

1. Change ExportBufferSizeKB=”512″ to 10240 and restart 'Mailbox Replication Service'
2. Disable indexing temporarily and enable it back once you complete migration.  Set-MailboxDatabase “DB1” -IndexEnabled:$False
3. Change MRSThroattling value from 1 to 0 here and restart 'Mailbox Replication Service'. As usual, re enable it back once migration is finished. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSExchange ResourceHealth
4. Another setting is set the priority as follows

New-MoveRequest -Identity “user@domain.com” -TargetDatabase “DB1” -Priority emergency

Remember that this last settings is applicable for only one mailbox. Set it for multiple mailboxes and see how it goes